# Terragrunt with modules of terraform using local state instead of s3 remote state

Tags: terraform, terragrunt, terraform-remote-state

I am using terragrunt to create an environment using the approach of storing the remote state into my local path.

```
remote_state {
  backend = "local"
  config = {
        path= "../..//mypath/terraform.tfstate"
  }
}
```

but because terragrunt downloads the terraform modules in a temporary folder by default .terragrunt-cache, it does not set them in the original path but in the temporary path.
I am using the following command in the path where my root file is located:

terragrunt run-all apply --terragrunt-download-dir C:\Tempfile
Using --terragrunt-download-dir but this will only downloads the temporal folder in a specific path and i want to set my terraform.tfstate in the original path not the temporary folder.

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine both the absolute and relative paths:

```
remote_state {
  backend = "local"
  config = {
    path = "${get_parent_terragrunt_dir()}/${path_relative_to_include()}/terraform.tfstate"
  }

  generate = {
    path = "backend.tf"
    if_exists = "overwrite"
  }
}
```

You'll know it's working when you see `terraform.tfstate` files in each folder containing a `terragrunt.hcl`.

More context: [terragrunt/issues/2179](https://github.com/gruntwork-io/terragrunt/issues/2179)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify where the **terraform.state** will be save by using TerraGrunt to write the backend.tf so that is also sets the path for the state file, like so:

```
remote_state {
  backend = "local"
  generate = {
    path      = "backend.tf"
    if_exists = "overwrite"
  }
  config = {
    path = "${get_terragrunt_dir()}/terraform.tfstate"
  }
}
```

backend.tf should look something like:

```
# Generated by Terragrunt. Sig: nIlQXj57tbuaRZEa
terraform {
  backend "local" {
    path = "C:/Users/Imposter/src/github.com/sample/technology-iac/test/iac-backend/terraform.tfstate"
  }
}
```

1. The `generate` block will generate a "backend.tf" file in the Terraform module that it downloads into the `.terragrunt-cache` directory.
2. The **get_terragrunt_dir()** function will be replace with the path to the directory that holds the **terragrunt.hcl**. See the TerraGrunt build-in function [get_terragrunt_dir()](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/reference/built-in-functions/#get_terragrunt_dir) for details.
3. That will cause Terraform to place the state file in the same directory as the terragrunt.hcl file.

Note this means that you would need to remove `backend` config from any other *.tf files.

Also, if you have **terragrunt.hcl** files that are only meant to be included in other terragrunt.hcl modules or do not produce any infrastructure, then you'll want to make use of TerraGrunt's [skip](https://terragrunt.gruntwork.io/docs/reference/config-blocks-and-attributes/#skip) attribute so the `run-all apply` command does not try to process them.

Tested with `terragrunt version v0.42.5` and `Terraform v1.3.6` on Windows.